# How to create a VM image?

Tags: virtual-machines

I've tried Googling, but haven't found the answer I'm looking for.

I want to create a VM image for our development setup at work, so we can spin up a new VM whenever a dev needs it with zero hassle. The VM will be CentOS with our server stack installed.

We use VMWare for our virtualization server. What's the best way to do this?

I particularly like how GitHub enterprise works. They give you a single file called a virtual appliance that you are able to import right into VMWare.

Comment: You use VMware what?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, I suspect VMWare ESXi. I am using VMWare Workstation on my personal machine in which I plan to make the VM image.

Comment: Start by talking to your VM infrastructure admins. If you don't know what platform or version you're running, you have not begun to adequately research the matter. Find out what they've already done for other teams and start from there. If they decide that you should be building this environment on top of a base image that they provision, you may be forced to start from scratch.

Comment: @AndrewB The whole reason I'm looking into it is because one of our "sysadmins" has been working on this as a top priority for months and hasn't gotten anywhere. I know the requirements and am confident I can do it inside of a week. VMWare Studio looks like its what I want.

Comment: This is almost trivial in vCenter. It would require a healthy dose of scripting without, but you could get there. It's definitely not something anyone should take "months" to get done. There's also self-serve provisioning portal in the Life Cycle Manager product (so your SysAdmin doesn't even have to do anything for new machines to be created; I'll preempt the thoughtless objection "then devs could run amok", the admin can set policies so the devs stay within limits and all sorts of easy).

Comment: It's a good idea to be up front about details like that; it changes the context of the problem quite a bit. SF regulars tend to frown on trying to bypass infrastructure admins unless it's clear they aren't getting the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to deploy a VM with a specific build template right?

You didn’t comment on what version of VMware you’re using so I’m guessing it comes with 
Vsphere.

Have a look here: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/162734